# JS Fetch api PUT method on multi-level json

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

Here's the json: https://api.myjson.com/bins/mpyk8
It's multilevel (as in there are objects within objects).

Getting the data from the json to my React Native app was easy, but I can't figure out how to update the json. (myjson, according to their docs, allows you to do so)

Now, I'm using js Fetch api, and wrote up this:

```
updatejson(){
  fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1b8i38/", {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({"location":"somevalue"}),
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    })
  .then((response) => {
    response.json().then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  })}
```

**How do I update an object within an object?** What should the body property look like? Is there some other trick to it?

Happy to explain the problem further, if I was unclear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *updating the body property* ? Please explain it

Comment: contentType and dataType are jquery options not fetch api options. You need to set the content-type header in the headers option eg: `headers:{'content-type':'application/json'}`

Comment: What needs to get updated is any of the values in the json (location for example). The question about the body propery was just me assuming that one of the mistakes is here: "body: JSON.stringify({"location":"somevalue"}),". @DominikMatis

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thank you! This made the code work. It deleted what was in the json and replaced everything with the new body (makes sense now that I think about it), which was not the intended behaviour. But that's a separate problem I guess.

Comment: You have it fixed as literal there, you should create an object variable which will contain all body like `let body = { 'location': 'somevalue' }` then you will be able to easily change the value with `body.location = 'somenewvalue'` and you will pass it as `body: JSON.stringify(body)`. that's all

Comment: Personally I would start by searching out a basic javascript tutorial. Once you master that the understanding that statements like "multi-level json" are nonsense will help you to formulate a question people can actually answer. JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is not hard to understand. The  JSON you linked describes and object with 3 properties: title (a string), descrtiption (a string), gasprices (an array). The gasprices array is an array of objects. So as asked before, what is it you want to update?

Comment: How do you access an element of an array? I'm not sure this qualifies as a "tip". `array[indexOfElement]` is how you access one. So in your example object, to access and edit the 2nd element of the `gasprices` array: `gasprices[1].price = "3.76"`

Comment: @gforce301 Sorry about the weird question formulation before. Regarding the solution, that would also have been my logic, but I have no clue how to achieve that with the fetch api. All I can do is pass some json in "Body". But that replaces the whole json.

Comment: I could update the json locally and then update myjson with the whole local json, but that's kinda dumb.

Comment: @WhiteLilac Ok here's the thing, I don't kow anything about this "myjson" api. As written your question can't be answered. Somewhere (I hope) there is documentation about this "myjson" api and in that documentation (I hope) it explains how to do what you want to do. My guess is though, that the only way to modify the remote version is to push a full copy (in other words the whole local version) up to them.

Comment: @WhiteLilac Ok I went and looked at their "docs" http://myjson.com/api. You have to send the entire object as a JSON string every time you wish to update it. Which means your application flow looks like this: Get the information from "myjson", Modify the information locally (as we have discussed), PUT the entire set of information back. It's the way their system works and I guess that's what you get for free.

Comment: Yeah. There's not much documentation on the myjson api. They just show that "PUT"/"PATCH"/"DELETE" are possible.

I'll update the json locally and push the full copy for now. And then switch to a more viable solution.

Thanks a lot for helping me reach a conclusion on this. Been struggling with it for way too long now.